# Is it possible to perform this raw sql query with related models in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, Count(order_product.product_id)
FROM products INNER JOIN (orders INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id) ON products.id = order_product.product_id
GROUP BY products.id, products.name
ORDER BY Count(order_product.product_id) DESC
```

I can't actually understand how to do it with models:

return Order::with('products')->get();

after this line of code im getting all my orders with related products in this order, but I can access them only by one order, I mean `I cant` do next for all orders:

```
return Order::with('products')->//all()//->products()->get();
```

I can do it only with 1 order like this:

```
return Order::with('products')->first()->products()->get() or
return Order::with('products')->find($id)->products()->get();
```

but I need all products from ALL orders.

Maybe im doing something wrong and I don't need to do what I described above to perform this query with related models?

Result of this query should be the most sellable products (products with highest frequency in orders)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The withCount() query builder method is probably the easiest way:

```
Product::withCount('orders')->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: how can i filter only products with orders count more than zero?
Trying this

Product::withCount(['orders'=>function($query){
        $query->where('orders_count','>','0');
    }])->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')->get();

but getting error :c

Comment: uhhhhhhh, adding ->having instead of where solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using DB::raw() for more specific/complicated queries. You would just do this:

Don't forget the "use DB;" at the top of the file!

```
$result = DB::raw("SELECT products.id, products.name, Count(order_product.product_id)
FROM products INNER JOIN (orders INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id) ON products.id = order_product.product_id
GROUP BY products.id, products.name
ORDER BY Count(order_product.product_id) DESC");
```